# There is already an object named 'Employee' in the database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I try to update my database, but I have this error:

> There is already an object named 'Employee' in the database.

This is my last migration file:

```
 public partial class explain : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Employee", "Person_PersonId", "dbo.Person");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Receptionist", "PersonId", "dbo.Employee");
            DropIndex("dbo.Employee", new[] { "Person_PersonId" });
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Employee",
                c => new
                    {
                        PersonId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Receptionist_PersonId = c.Int(),
                        Salary = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Hiredate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        isManager = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.PersonId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Person", t => t.PersonId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Receptionist", t => t.Receptionist_PersonId)
                .Index(t => t.PersonId)
                .Index(t => t.Receptionist_PersonId);

            AddForeignKey("dbo.Receptionist", "PersonId", "dbo.Employee", "PersonId");
            DropTable("dbo.Employee");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Employee",
                c => new
                    {
                        PersonId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Salary = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Hiredate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        isManager = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        Person_PersonId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.PersonId);

            DropForeignKey("dbo.Employee", "Receptionist_PersonId", "dbo.Receptionist");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Receptionist", "PersonId", "dbo.Employee");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Employee", "PersonId", "dbo.Person");
            DropIndex("dbo.Employee", new[] { "Receptionist_PersonId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Employee", new[] { "PersonId" });
            DropTable("dbo.Employee");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Employee", "Person_PersonId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Receptionist", "PersonId", "dbo.Employee", "PersonId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Employee", "Person_PersonId", "dbo.Person", "PersonId");
        }
    }
```

Employee.cs model

```
public class Employee : Person
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            EmployeeSchedule = new HashSet<EmployeeSchedule>();
            Vacation = new HashSet<Vacation>();
        }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Wynagrodzenie")]
        public int Salary { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Data zatrudnienia")]
        public DateTime Hiredate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Kierownik")]
        public bool isManager { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EmployeeSchedule> EmployeeSchedule { get; set; }

        public virtual Lifeguard Lifeguard { get; set; }

        public virtual Receptionist Receptionist { get; set; }

        public virtual Trainer Trainer { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Vacation> Vacation { get; set; }
    }
```

Person.cs

```
public abstract class Person
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public long Pesel { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Imię nie może zawierać więcej niż 30 znaków.")]
        [Display(Name = "Imię")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Nazwisko nie może zawierać wiecej niż 60 znaków.")]
        [Display(Name = "Nazwisko")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Błędny format adresu e-mail.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Data urodzenia")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth  { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public int age;
        [NotMapped]
        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
                age = today.Year - DateOfBirth.Year;
                if (DateOfBirth > today.AddYears(-age))
                {
                    age--;
                }
                return age;
            }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name="Imię i Nazwisko")]
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstName + " " + LastName;
            }
        }

    }
```

Stack Trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named
>   'Employee' in the database.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2418102
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5694456    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +3731
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +959
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) +272
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +280
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand
>   t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +36
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +138
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +476
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   +177    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement
>   migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +194
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement
>   migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +62
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +113
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext) +110
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext) +172
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext) +429
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection) +646
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
>   +66    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +34    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +251
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation) +196
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction) +327
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements) +39
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements) +42
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String
>   migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations,
>   IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>   +1372    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
>   migration, DbMigration lastMigration) +783
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
>   migration, DbMigration lastMigration) +56
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   +192    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   +59    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration) +888
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b() +38
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +516
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +42
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration) +136
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update() +33
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext
>   internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
>   +175    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext
>   objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +150
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState) +444
>   System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context) +158
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__e()
>   +165    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action) +110
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>   +660    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4(InternalContext
>   c) +31
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
>   +143    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
>   action) +292
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>   +123    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +42    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +39
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +137
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +38    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +58
>
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +70
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(Object[] keyValues) +69
>
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.EntityStore`1.GetByIdAsync(Object
>   id) +104
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.d__6c.MoveNext()
>   +275    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +28    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +123    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<b__1>d__4.MoveNext()
>   +1519    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.d__2.MoveNext()
>   +3729    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +28    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext()
>   +810    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +427    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +641    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +641    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +641    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +641    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext()
>   +287    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__2.MoveNext()
>   +272    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.Rethrow() +33 
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +150
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +42
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +380    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: delete your database and run `update-database`

Comment: @gldraphael the same problem

Comment: you've been down voted for some reason, consider moving the stacktrace to a service like pastebin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving the DropTable statement up before the Create statement in the migration. This way you drop the existing Employee table before creating a new one.